# What is the difference between scope creep and scope gap?

Tags: scope

As per understanding from given [link](https://www.pmi.org/learning/library/top-five-causes-scope-creep-6675), scope creep is unapproved additional works, requirements or features of a new product. But I am not clear about: what, then, is scope gap? As per definition, scope gap is specifications or activities added to the project late. Can someone elaborate with a working example in a software project?

Comment: Even the link you pointed to gives a much better definition of scope creep than what you summarized. I think your takeaway from it was too narrow.

Comment: "Scope gap are features that I want implemented. Scope creep are features you want implemented." /s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It’s All About Expectations

“Unapproved” doesn’t really capture the essence of scope creep. In purely pragmatic terms, scope creep is a slow or gradual increase in scope beyond the original plan. A scope gap (which is not really a very common term, in my personal business experience) is just the shortfall between stakeholder expectations of included scope and the project’s planned or delivered features.

In either case, the issue is that non-agile scope is often considered fixed, so scope creep and scope gaps are common. In contrast, agile projects continuously refine and renegotiate scope, so scope creep is typically less of a problem, and scope gaps can’t exist beyond a single iteration.